# Git/Sourcetree Manage multiple project with the same base

Tags: git, github, multisite, sourcetree

I have a project of three sites with the same base.
The sites are builded in Zend Framework so the structure is as follow:

[image]

Only the /application/modules is used as base as the rest (might) contain site specific content.

I want to setup the Git/Sourcetree that i can maintain all the projects at once, my suggestion is to use Subtree but i don't know how to configure that right.

My site structure would be basic at this:

- Head company:

  - Sub company 1
  - Sub company 2
  - Sub company 3

I've created a repo for all 4 companies (the head and the 3 subs)
How can i put the Base in the Head repo and the styling/config in the Sub repo and manage the base within all three sub repos, see TL;DR for meaning (assuming that pull and push are done right).

TL;DR
What i want to achieve is that i can open the repo of a single site, edit the base and whenever i open a second repo (with pull and pushing done) i get the same base within that repo and continue from there.

*I have never used any complex stuff within GIT so it's hard for to configure it right*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `modules` a Git [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) so it can be used in multiple projects.

Each company project would have it's own repository, but in each of those repositories, put a `.gitmodules` file at the base that looks like this:

```
[submodule "application/modules"]
    path = application/modules
    url = //path/to/modules/repository
```

To initialize the `modules` submodule in each repository run `git submodule update --init`.

You can then work within the `modules` repository in any project, commit, and push, then pull those changes into any of the other projects simply by going into that project's `modules` submodule and running `git pull` (or by using `git submodule foreach git pull` from the project's base repository).